# Unity4.6.3でのMobileSingleStickControlRigについて

Tags: unity3d

MobileSingleStickControlRigを使用し、スティックの配置を行いたいのですが、
スティックに触れると0,0の座標に移動されてしまいます。

スティックの配置場所を、そのまま維持したいのですが、どうすれば初期の配置を維持することができるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

MobileSingleStick の Canvas に Canvas Scaler を追加して
UI Scale Mode を Scale With Screen Size に設定することだけで
ある程度まで対応できます。(Unity5.0.1 にて同様の現象に対応)

参考
http://unitymemonote.blogspot.jp/2015/03/asset-mobilesinglestickcontrol.html
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/917671/unity5-joystick-prefab-snapping-to-bottom-left-cor.html

追記
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/917671/unity5-joystick-prefab-snapping-to-bottom-left-cor.html
のコメントにあるように JoyStick.cs の onEnable() を Start() に変更するといいようです。

> // void onEnable()
>      void Start()
>      {
>          m_StartPos = transform.position;
>          CreateVirtualAxes();
>      }